# Python: Converting MySQL datetime to datetime for format

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

Bit of a newbie here.

I have a program which takes results from a MySQL database.
It picks out the fields Id and ship_date, the query searches only for returned records based on a given Id.
The results should be 2 or more dates which it does.
My aim is to have formatted the dates and compare the days between them.
The results are put into separate lists, so I get two lists like this:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 28, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 28, 0, 0),)]
```

and

```
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 06, 15, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(2012, 08, 19, 0, 0),)]
```

for instance.

But when I attempt to turn the whole list into a readable format with a piece of code I found:

```
ship_date = [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt in ship_date]
```

I always get an error that there is no attribute strftime.
I have tried turning them into strings and then using strftime, but I get the error that str has no attribute strftime.
I'm at a complete loss.

Btw, I have imported datetime

Does anyone have any ways I can turn these lists (2 of them) into readable formats like

```
2012-12-28, 2012-12-28
```

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, what does a raw MySQL datetime look like in a string format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given list contains tuples with datetime, not just datetime. So the items should be unpacked.

```
>>> ship_dates = [(datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 28, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 28, 0, 0),)]
>>> [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt in ship_dates]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'

>>> [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for (dt,) in ship_dates]
['2012-12-28', '2012-12-28']
```

Or you can omit `(..)`:

```
>>> [dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for dt, in ship_dates]
['2012-12-28', '2012-12-28']
```